# Can we [safely] remove this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

We have a [safely](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/safely) tag. I don't really like it and think we should burninate it.

Burnination criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

This tag is ambigous. It's something about (attempting to) do something safely, but that is rather vauge.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Sure! Doing things without breaking your system is on topic. It's still a bad tag.

> Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

No.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No. It can refer to

- If a file/directory can be removed safely ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1413698/snap-folders-on-ubuntu-focal-20-04))
- If an arbitrary setup is safe ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1239284/how-safe-is-this-remote-rsync-setup))
- Trying to do risky actions safely ([example 1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219155/what-is-the-best-way-to-upgrade-all-packages-if-you-use-a-desktop-pc-without-a-n), [example 2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141064/how-can-i-test-a-shell-script-in-a-safe-environment-to-avoid-harm-to-my-comput))
- Safely removing external storage ([example](https://askubuntu.com/questions/463214/safely-remove-option-for-external-devices-removed-from-ubuntu-14-04))

---

Given that, I think this tag should go.

Comment: I agree. That tag makes no sense. There are only 12 questions tagged with it. I would recommend just editing them all and removing/replacing that tag. (12 questions for 4 different meanings is just absurd lol)

Comment: And another voice of agreement here, and as mentioned it would be a simple matter to prune the tag out manually.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have removed the last of the tags today; it was raining and cold outside so a perfect day for some tag housekeeping :).

The tag should vanish after 24 hours of non-use but if it is created again we can start the formal process of [burnination...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239190/662263)